# Проблема с созданием объкта и добавлением его на сцену

Tags: c++, qt

Есть объект figure, класса Figure, класс наследуется от QGraphicsPixmapItem, если я создаю объект следующим образом:

```
Figure *figure = new Figure("BLACK", parent)
```

то я спокойно могу добавить фигуру на сцену, но я не могу занести фигуру в QVector этих фигур, изменим создание фигуры на такой вид:

```
Figure figure("BLACK", parent);
```

она спокойно заносится в QVector, но добавить ее на сцену я не могу, что делать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто видимо Ваш вектор объявлен вот так

```
QVector<Figure> vec;
```

Объявите где то так

```
QVector<Figure*> vec;
```

и все должно заработать.

Comment: Если не затрудню, в чем разница между этими объявлениями вектора?

Comment: в одном случае в векторе будут хранится сами элементы (фигуры) и при добавлении они будут туда копироваться. Вектор сам побеспокоится о их удалении. В втором случае будут хранится только указатели. И в общем нужно не забывать корректно освобождать память. Да, в этом конкретном случае скорее всего все будет ок - там есть parent, который сам все сделает. Но обычно это не так.